# Anything wrong with my sudoku hiddensingles method?

Tags: java, sudoku

I am writing a sudoku using java and now I can solve some of simple sudokus, but when I test for hiddensingles method, the test said there are something wrong in my hiddensingles method.

This is candidates method and hiddensingles method I wrote:

```
    public boolean[] candidates(int row, int column) {
            boolean[] candidates = new boolean[10];
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                candidates[i] = true;
            }
            if (board[row][column] == 0){
                for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                    for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++) {
                        if(board[row][a] == i)
                            candidates[i] = false;
                        if(board[a][column] == i) 
                            candidates[i] = false;
                    }
                    for(int Tr = row / 3 * 3; Tr < row / 3 * 3 + 3; Tr ++) {
                        for(int Tc = column / 3 * 3; Tc < column /3 * 3 +3; Tc ++) {
                            if(board[Tr][Tc] == i)
                                candidates[i] = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                    candidates[i] = false;
                }
            }
            return candidates;
        }

public boolean hiddenSingles() {
        boolean[][][] checkHiddenSingles = new boolean[9][9][10];
        boolean hiddenSingles = false;
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < 9; column++) {
                for( int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
                    checkHiddenSingles[row][column][i] = candidates(row, column)[i];
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i ++){
            int numOfCandidates;
            //hiddenSingles = false;
            for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < 9; column++) {
                    if(checkHiddenSingles[row][column][i]) {
                        if ( !hiddenSingles ) {
                            numOfCandidates = 0;
                            for(int Tr = 0; Tr < 9; Tr ++) {
                                if(checkHiddenSingles[Tr][column][i] /*&& Tr != row*/){ 
                                    numOfCandidates ++;
                                }            
                            }
                            if(numOfCandidates == 1) {
                                board[row][column] = i;
                                hiddenSingles = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (!hiddenSingles) {
                            numOfCandidates = 0;
                            for(int Tc = 0; Tc < 9; Tc ++) {
                                if(checkHiddenSingles[row][Tc][i] /*&& Tc != column*/){
                                    numOfCandidates ++;
                                }          
                            }
                            if(numOfCandidates == 1) {
                                board[row][column] = i ;
                                hiddenSingles = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else if(!hiddenSingles) {
                            numOfCandidates = 0;
                            int Tr = row / 3;
                            int Tc = column / 3;
                            for (int Cr = Tr * 3; Cr < Cr + 3; Cr++) {
                                for(int Cc = Tc * 3; Cc < Cc + 3; Cc++) {
                                    if(checkHiddenSingles[Tr][Tc][i] /*&& 
                                            (row != Tr && column != Tc)*/ )
                                        numOfCandidates ++;
                                }
                            }
                            if ( numOfCandidates == 1 ) {
                                hiddenSingles = true;
                                board[row][column] = i ;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return hiddenSingles;
    }
```

ps:board is a 9*9 2d array 
and this is the information about hiddensingle: http://hodoku.sourceforge.net/en/tech_singles.php#h1

Comment: "but when I test for hiddensingles method, the test said there are something wrong in my hiddensingles method." can you tell us what it says a stack trace perhaps ... Have you tried debugging your code ?

Comment: Sorry about that, the test case is provided by others and the only information I get is  "testHiddenSingles(): (0,1) is wrong". I think I've passed other tests since there no other error test case told me. And yes, I tried many times but still don't know to solve this problem.